# "мобильное" отображение select multiple

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

На рабочей платформе (сайт на php) необходимо сделать страничку с формами для обмена данными. С этим приложением пользователь будет работать как с пк, так и с телефона (с телефона вход на страничку будет осуществляться не по адресу в браузере, а через подключение к виртуальному рабочему столу).

Если входить в браузер непосредственно с телефона , то select'ы с параметром multiple работают особым образом, позволяя tuch'ем выбирать несколько значений, либо раскрываются доп. меню с выбором нескольких вариантов. Браузер видимо "понимает", что ты с телефона зашел. Если же с телефона подключаться к виртуальному рабочему столу и оттуда войти в браузер - он "думает", что ты с компа сидишь и никакие элементы формы не переключаются на вид "для телефона". С multiple select работать очень неудобно.

Можно как-нибудь "объяснить" браузеру, что элемент нужно отобразить, будто он отображается для пользователя с телефона? Стандартные параметры для html тега не нашел, хитрости css тоже. Неужели в этом случае остается городить на javascript доп функционал для работы с мультиселектом?

Comment: Можно использовать media queries в CSS. Это позволяет применять различные стили к элементам в зависимости от размера экрана. Например, можно создать media query с минимальной шириной экрана для телефона и применять соответствующие стили к элементу select.

Comment: @IrshatKhuzin Проблема не совсем в стилях. Проблема в том что само поведение селекта меняется если пользователь со смартфона. Браузер либо доп меню отрисовывает, либо реагирует на tuch по другому. С компа клик по option в select с multiple переключает варианты, оставляя только выбранный, пока ты не зажмешь ctrl, а с телефона любой tuch добавляет элементы к выбранным

Answer (score 0):

Опция  с возможностью мультивыбора осуществляеться с зажиманием клавиши 'Ctrl(or Command)' может вам проще какой-то пояснительний плейсхолдер повесить. Когда решал похожую задачу реализовывал [вот такой](https://habr.com/ru/post/564844/) Городить что-то самопальное, с запретами отображений очень не рекомендую, поскольку очень много косяков потом по браузерной совместимости вылазит.(особенно старые Айфоны)